# Move C:\Users\tachikoma01\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin to an other hardrive

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, mklink, roaming-profiles

I have a 120gb ssd and it's full.  I want to use bitcoin armory which is going to take up to 50gb. And even if the software is installed on my G: hard drive, the software is still downloading datas to C:\Users\tachikoma01\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin.
So I'd like to have the software use G:\Roaming\Bitcoin and don't take any space on my C drive.
I believe I can use some sort of symbolic link but I failed to do it.
Can anyone tell me how to do that please?

Comment: I tried MKLINK/J "C:\Users\tachikoma01\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin" "G:\Roaming\Bitcoin" in execute. It didn't work so I tried to do it with administrator prompt. It kind of worked, but the software was still copying on C: everytime... Even when I made sure to delete the folde on C first

Comment: Update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure to move `C:\Users\tachikoma01\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin` to the new location at `G:\Roaming\Bitcoin`, and make sure that your Bitcoin mining software is off and doesn't re-create the folder when you move it.

Once you're sure the folder is no longer there, you can create a symbolic link. The easiest way to create a symlink in windows is at the command prompt, using the `MKLINK` command. The command you want is

```
MKLINK /D "C:\Users\tachikoma01\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin" "G:\Roaming\Bitcoin"
```

This creates a symlink at `C:\Users\...\Bitcoin` which points to `G:\Roaming\Bitcoin`. The `\D` specifies that you're symlinking a folder (or "directory"), not a regular file.